# Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' has no member 'dbRestClient'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to save images to Dropbox. When I use this line:     `self.dbRestClient.uploadFile(uploadFilename, toPath: destinationPath, withParentRev: nil, fromPath: sourcePath)`

**Error:**

> Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' has no member
>   'dbRestClient'.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, DBRestClientDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tblFiles: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var bbiConnect: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!

    var dbRestClient: DBRestClient!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tblFiles.delegate = self
        tblFiles.dataSource = self

        progressBar.hidden = true


         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleDidLinkNotification:", name: "didLinkToDropboxAccountNotification", object: nil)

        if DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked() {
            bbiConnect.title = "Disconnect"
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: IBAction method implementation

    @IBAction func connectToDropbox(sender: AnyObject) {

        if !DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked() {
                DBSession.sharedSession().linkFromController(self)
            }
            else {
                DBSession.sharedSession().unlinkAll()
                bbiConnect.title = "Connect"
            dbRestClient = nil
            }

        if DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked() {
            bbiConnect.title = "Disconnect"
        }

    }


    @IBAction func performAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        if !DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked() {
            print("You're not connected to Dropbox")
            return
        }

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Upload file", message: "Select file to upload", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let uploadTextFileAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload text file", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

        }

        let uploadImageFileAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload image", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) -> Void in

        }

        actionSheet.addAction(uploadTextFileAction)
        actionSheet.addAction(uploadImageFileAction)
        actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func reloadFiles(sender: AnyObject) {

    }


    // MARK: UITableview method implementation

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }

    func handleDidLinkNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        initDropboxRestClient()
        bbiConnect.title = "Disconnect"
    }



    func initDropboxRestClient() {
        dbRestClient = DBRestClient(session: DBSession.sharedSession())
        dbRestClient.delegate = self
    }




    let uploadTextFileAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload text file", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

        let uploadFilename = "testtext.txt"
        let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testtext", ofType: "txt")
        let destinationPath = "/"

        self.dbRestClient.uploadFile(uploadFilename, toPath: destinationPath, withParentRev: nil, fromPath: sourcePath)
    }

    let uploadImageFileAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload image", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

        let uploadFilename = "nature.jpg"
        let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nature", ofType: "jpg")
        let destinationPath = "/"

        self.dbRestClient.uploadFile(uploadFilename, toPath: destinationPath, withParentRev: nil, fromPath: sourcePath)
    }

    func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, uploadedFile destPath: String!, from srcPath: String!, metadata: DBMetadata!) {
        print("The file has been uploaded.")
        print(metadata.path)
    }

    func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, uploadFileFailedWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("File upload failed.")
        print(error.description)
    }


}
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be because the "let uploadTextFileAction" is outside of any function. Try moving it inside viewDidLoad just to see if it compiles.

Comment: @MikeTaverne That does the trick. Thanks. Please add that as the answer

Comment: glad it worked, but I'm not sure why, so I don't feel I have really answered the question.

Comment: @MikeTaverne I tried that but now when I put it inside a function it won't run :  let uploadImageFileAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload image", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
            
            let uploadFilename = "nature.jpg"
            let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nature", ofType: "jpg")
            let destinationPath = "/"
            
            self.dbRestClient.uploadFile(uploadFilename, toPath: destinationPath, withParentRev: nil, fromPath: sourcePath)
            print("sdsdas")
        }

Comment: And when it does I get a breakpoint on this line: self.dbRestClient.uploadFile(uploadFilename, toPath: destinationPath, withParentRev: nil, fromPath: sourcePath) . What's happening?

Comment: I solved the problem but I don't know how. I moved the code into the performAction function. I then changed the self.dbRestClient.upload() to this : let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nature", ofType: "jpg")
            self.dbRestClient.uploadFile("nature.jpg", toPath: "/", withParentRev: nil, fromPath: sourcePath) @MikeTaverne

Answer (score 0):

Change your constants that access `self` like `self.dbRestClient` to `lazy var`. Only lazy and computed properties can access `self` in their initialisation. 
e.g. the first one will look like:

```
lazy var uploadTextFileAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload text file", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

   let uploadFilename = "testtext.txt"
   let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testtext", ofType: "txt")
   let destinationPath = "/"

   self.dbRestClient.uploadFile(uploadFilename, toPath: destinationPath, withParentRev: nil, fromPath: sourcePath)
}
```